# Bootstrap 3 sidebar fixed in border left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know, how I can make a sidebar with left margin 0 in the bootstrap 3.

For better explanation, see this example :
[Site example](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0246423)

I would like this structure of the side bar.

Comment: Can you show us or explain what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap (2 or 3) doesn't offer the possibility of including a left/right sidebar.
You have to put a `<div>` with a fixed position, and a `height: 100%`, aligned to `left: 0`